# How to stop the obvious spam in messenger without removing contact?

Tags: windows-live-messenger, spam-prevention, hotmail, report

A trusted friend of mine has been sending me spam for the last few weeks. This is obviously hacked or something. But I don't which account is it since his yahoo, facebook, linkedin and what not accounts are all linked together in messenger contacts. He seems blaise about doing something about it, and it is getting tiring to just ignore it day after day! (It is the first message that greets me every day). There is not even an option of "My friend has been hacked" like in Outlook/Hotmail for emails. Where I can report such stuff to Microsoft? Help!

PS: I am prevented from posting a picture of the screenshot!

Comment: What do you mean by "they are all linked together in messenger contacts"? Is it only a link in your client on your side or are the three accounts fundamentally the same? In the first case, you can probably unlink them temporarily, but in the second case I guess that if one account has been hacked them all three are.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* an option to report hacked accounts to microsoft: on windows live messenger, you can go to:

`Actions (3rd from the top left)`, `Compromised (bottom row)`

I don't have an english install, but it should be close to the above.

Also, note that he can just change his password, and the bots that are spamming with his account won't be able to connect anymore.

Comment: I am not using the client for windows live messenger, but the service of messenger that is available on hotmail.

Comment: you can either install it or ask the hacked person to change the password